# ASP.Net create new user control using JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, user-controls

I know you can can do this using MVC. But not sure if you can using Web Forms.

I have a button, when clicked it will get the data then populate a repater then injects the data to other controls. This works fine using postback, but it's a little slow and I want to do it using Ajax.

Is there a way to use JQuery to instantiate the repeater control or the user controls without using postback or using evil update panels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a page that handles *just* the repeater, and use jQuery to request that page via ajax you can set the inner html of a container to the response returned by your requested fragment.

```
<div id="repeater-goes-here"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $.ajax('repeater.aspx', null, success: function(responseText) {
           $('#repeater-goes-here').html(responseText);
       };
   });
</script>
```

The 'repeater.aspx' page should contain the repeater object and the code required to populate it from data.

Comment: found pretty cool ScottGu link: 

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx